# Laravel - image not showing - defies logic

Tags: php, laravel, image

Site is a few years old - Laravel 5.1

When first set up, all images (uploaded to public/images), displayed correctly using, for example:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/services-1.jpg') }}" title = "Services" />
```

in blade templates.

Now, I have uploaded (FTP) a replacement image called services-2.jpg and edited the blade template to change the filename - and, guess what, I get the placeholder box on the page and the image does not show. Even if I just copy the orginal image file and rename it with the changed filename - again, no show.

I have tested a new img tag on the home page - first I used an image file that was originally uploaded - that worked. Then I just changed the file to one recently added - no show.

So, just by referencing a more recent image file - it changes from show to no show. No other changes.

I have done the clear storage/framewor/cache and views folders - no change.

I am stuck as to what else might cause this behaviour - any thoughts?

Comment: You are getting a 404 not found on your image? For clearing cache please try `php artisan optimize:clear`. Can you load the generated URL in a new tab and see the image? Can you try to remove the `/` before `images/service-1.jpg`?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the images?

Comment: Hi Christopher. Loading the url for one of the original images: <site>/images/services-1.jpg - works fine. The same url with the recent image <site>/images/services-2.jpg fails and gives an error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 - weird huh? Thanks for looking at it for me

Comment: Also - `php artisan optimize:clear` returns an error "There are no commands defined in the "optimize" namespace" - probably due to the version of Laravel I am using. Hoping to avoid having to change the version just to show a new image -  a little overkill I think. Thanks again

Comment: Bang on kerbholz! Permissions were the same but ownership and group were different - that's what comes of accessing using different ftp accounts. Yay - thanks a lot. Moving on...

Answer (score 0):

kerbholz nailed it by pointing at the permissions on the image files. It was less permissions and more user:group ownership. I had used a different FTP account to upload the image and so ownership differed from the original files. Changed ownership and it worked fine - used:

```
chown <user>:<group> <file>
```

Thanks for all responses / comments